# Export translations of field labels

Tags: entities, i18n-l10n

Drupal 7. I work on multi language site. I have a content type with entity translation fields. I've added translation to field labels and settings on my DEV copy of site and now I need to export and import it to Production.

[image: Field translation settings]

Is there any module in Drupal 7, that helps me to export and import field labels/settings? Or maybe someone tell me, how to export values from "locales_source" and "locales_target" tables and import it to my Production database? Because I see only "lid" auto increment field in both tables.

[image: Locales Source table]
Locales Source table

[image: Locales Target table]
Locales Target table

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved by Drupal standard translation export. I just check "Fields" and select "Existing strings and the plural format are kept, only new strings are added." when Import *.po file.

admin/config/regional/translate/export

[image]